How can I select the default encoding for a new text resource file in visual studio 2019?
I am developing a desktop application which relies on text resource files which I create using VS 2019.
In particular I create the files by selecting "My Project" under my project's name in Solution Explorer and then selecting Resources -> Add Resource -> Add New Text File.
This creates a blank text file which is encoded in my computer's default encoding (in my case CP1253) - however I would like the new text files to be encoded in UTF-8 instead.
The solution I have found so far is to manually change the encoding afterwards using an iconv script and updating the Resources.resx file to tell the files are encoded in utf8. I also can create the utf8 encoded files using an external tool like Notepad and then import them in VS.
Both solutions worked fine, however I was wondering if I can change the default encoding of the Resource text files created with Visual Studio to UTF 8 which would be really handy.

Suggestion: it might be more convenient to just add an existing text file in the correct encoding, and set it to output with your EXE, rather than include it in the resx file. Especially if you might want to edit the text file after deployment

After adding your text file, open it in the IDE.
Then click File > Save TextFile1.txt As...
The Save button has a little down arrow. Click the down arrow and select Save with Encoding... to change the encoding.
